# HELP! I'm locked out of all Ubuntu accounts

Tags: login, users, administration

I was using these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
gksu nautilus
```

I needed to move some files from one account into another & then I wanted to rename some of the accounts.  I got a failure message & my desktop wallpaper went black.

I logged out & now I cannot log into ANY account at all.  One account is my son's (with his school homework on it) & the other is mine (an admin).  There is no password on my son's but I have one on mine.

I cannot get into either account...I am brought back to the login screen.  I can't even get to a terminal to make any changes.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What I'm telling you is no solution but a resource to get the data stored in your HD. Boot from a Live USB or Live DVD and then you can access the data stored in your HD. It'd be wise to back it up.

Comment: I guess you have "rename(d) some of the accounts" by renaming the home folders. Is it right? If this is the case, then you can use a LiveCD to re-rename the folders back to their original names.

Comment: Andrea, you are correct.  I was renaming some folders.  I posted this on the Ubuntu Forums which described what I was doing:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185425&p=12836740#post12836740

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hold [shift] during boot you will get a textmode menu.
Choose  `(recovery mode)`

After boot you will be greeted by a colorful texmode screen
choose `root`

Make the system read/write

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

add a new user to your system:

```
adduser emergency
```

give this sudo permission:

```
addgroup emergency sudo
```

just reboot with `reboot` and login with your freshly made account.
If this all works out OK you can start repairing the things that went wrong.

Good Luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for your edit Elfy, I completely forgot that one.

Comment: I successfully created an "emergency" account & was able to access my data. I got a couple of notices saying there were some things that are wrong but I could not report them... However, I did rename the folders to their original names & rebooted. Yet I am still unable to log into either the Admin or my son's account. I can login successfully to the "emergency" account but the other 2 continue to bring me back to the login screen.

Comment: You probably hosed some very important files, but don't worry. Just make new accounts for you and your son. Then copy the contents from the old accounts to the new ones. If that all works OK then you can delete the old accounts and directories. Don't forget to backup the hidden files in your respective home directories.

Comment: I have an "emergency" account created with sudo that I was able to get into & run a terminal window.  I deleted the old "Leslie02" and the "username" account.  They did not show up when I used the GUI to bring up the User Accounts.  So I logged out of the "emergency" account & tried to log in to the new accounts I set up...and was brought back to the login screens just like before.  So I am no further along that I was.

Comment: If you couldn't login in your new accounts then you didn't create them properly. It is not enough to just make some directories. After you logged in as "emergency", press on the cogwheel icon on the launcher-bar and then press on the users and accounts icon. If you only see one "person" in the left pane, just add two more.

Comment: I looked in the file manager & saw that there were the old account home folders (username and Leslie02) in there.  When I tried to run the command, "sudo userdel -r Leslie02", it said nothing existed.  And I can't delete the old folders either.  How do purge everything associated with the old accounts & start all over with one Admin account for me & one User account for my son without having to reinstall Ubuntu all over again for the third time???  I've spent all day on this & I'm ready to go out & just buy a copy of Windows.

Comment: Thank you, Elfy, for your small piece of info.  I was able to successfully untangle things.  I used the rw command to delete the old home folders for the accounts I could not log into & using the emergency account was able to successfully re-create 2 new accounts to use.