# Locked out of root

Tags: 16.04, permissions, root, chmod

I messed up `chmod` (set all to `644` by a stupid accident) and now I am locked out of the admin account. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370089/help-im-locked-out-of-all-ubuntu-accounts) and created an emergency account successfully but when I try to log in I am stuck in a log in loop.

Is there any way to fix this or do I have to `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`? I am using a VMware remote console to access the computer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need root privilege (through either `sudo` or by root login) to use `apt-get` that way.

Comment: I have access to the shell through recovery mode. Will that work?

Comment: yes you can fix it in recovery, but what exactly did you chmod? if it was EVERYTHING (using `-R` flag) you have a long battle ahead - might be easier to get your personal files backed up and reinstall

Comment: I ran `sudo chmod 664 /` thinking it would only `chmod` the files in the current folder. How stupid. Will reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` through the shell reinstall everything with correct permissions etc? I don't have much on that system, mainly just apache but all files are backed up on git.

Answer (score 1):

Phew, I managed to fix it. I realised that I had only changed the permissions of the `/` folder, not recursively. What I did is I went into the recovery mode and into the root shell. Then ran `mount -o remount,rw /` and `sudo chmod 755 /`.

That'll teach me a lesson to be much more careful with `chmod`.

Thanks @Zanna for the help.

Comment: glad you fixed it, +1 for working it out yourself